# Re-emit to the same relay after mapping with bidirectional binding in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I've got a bidirectional binding event in the view controller like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ....
    func viewDidLoad(_ animated) {
        ...
        (textField.rx.text <-> viewModel.textRelay).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
    ....
}
```

And then in the view model:

```
class ViewModel {
     ...
    let textRelay: BehaviorRelay<String>
    
    init() {
        ...
        textRelay
            .map { $0.localizedUppercase }
            .bind(to: textRelay)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

What I am trying to do is uppercase the input and reemit so that the textfield will be automatically changed (since it is bidirectionally bound). It doesn't work as I though it would've. The textfield isn't getting the uppercased text. I know how to do this by using a `Driver<String?>`. But I was wondering is there a way to do this with bidirectional binding?

Thanks.

Comment: What library implements `<->` and is it implemented correctly?

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that your view model code creates an infinite loop. Every time the textRelay emits a value (and it emits as soon as `bind` is executed) it receives a value which causes it to emit a value, *ad infinitum*.

Comment: You could solve it by breaking the loop, for example with a `.distinctUntilChanged()` operator, but even then, when the user inserted text into the middle the cursor would jump to the end.

Comment: @DanielT. I'm using this: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxBiBinding . So what I can gather form your comments is that we can't actually do that?

Thanks BTW. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a fan of two way binding. I prefer unidirectional data flow.